# Trying to write a java program to send email but getting error

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I'm new in Java world and trying to create a small app to send email to my gmail account. But I am getting some error which I tried to solve, but failed. My full code is the following:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class SendMyEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        System.out.println("Hello");


        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        String msgBody = "...";

        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("tinyNina@gmail.com", "Example.com Admin"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                             new InternetAddress("tinyNina@gmail.com", "Mr. User"));
            msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");
            msg.setText(msgBody);
            Transport.send(msg);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (AddressException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
            // ...
        } catch (MessagingException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
            // ...
        }
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Hello
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect


        }

    }
```

Can anybody tell me where I am doing some mistake?

Note: I tried lots of ways and then I found a google link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/ and then I tried and getting that error.

Comment: why would you expect this to go to gmail.com?  Where do you think this is set?  try looking more at the javamail javadocs.

Comment: i tried to send mail to my own email.

Comment: You need to set a mail server, for the [obvious](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30362819/2970947) next question.

Comment: [This](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) may also add some additional insight

Comment: Don't forget the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).